# Right way to calculate the cosine similarity of two word-frequency-dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk, cosine-similarity

I'm trying to iterate through a file containing text and calculate the cosine similarity between the current line and a query the user raised. I have already tokenized the query and the line and saved the union of their words into a set.

Example:

```
line_tokenized = ['Karl', 'Donald', 'Ifwerson']

query_tokenized = ['Donald', 'Trump']

word_set = ['Karl', 'Donald', 'Ifwerson', 'Trump']
```

Now I have to create a dictionary each for the line and the query, containing word-frequency pairs. I thought about something ike this:

```
line_dict = {'Karl': 1, 'Donald': 1, 'Ifwerson': 1, 'Trump': 0}
query_dict = {'Karl': 0, 'Donald': 1, 'Ifwerson': 0, 'Trump': 1}
```

But the cosine similarity won't be calculated properly as the key-value pairs are unordered. I came across `OrderedDict()`, but I don't understand how to implement some things as it's elements are stored as tuples:

So my questions are:

- How can I set the key-value pairs and have access to them afterwards?
- How can I increment the value of a certain key?
- Or is there any other more easier way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "key-value pairs are unordered"? How would you expect them to be ordered?

Comment: I'd like them to stay in the order I add them to the dictionary.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that, I don't see in your code which order you refer to, I have a good answer for you, just explain to me the order

Comment: @LucaIonescu: a dictionary is a hashtable and thus has no inherent order. You can indeed use datastructures to enforce order, but to calculate the cos sim, that is not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to order the dictionary for [Cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity), simple lookup is sufficient:

```
import math

def cosine_dic(dic1,dic2):
    numerator = 0
    dena = 0
    for key1,val1 in dic1.items():
        numerator += val1*dic2.get(key1,0.0)
        dena += val1*val1
    denb = 0
    for val2 in dic2.values():
        denb += val2*val2
    return numerator/math.sqrt(dena*denb)
```

you simply use a `.get(key1,0.0)` to lookup of the element exists and if it does not `0.0` is assumed. As a result both `dic1` and `dic2` do not need to store values with `0` as value.

To answer your additional questions:

> How can I set the key-value pairs and have access to them afterwards?

You simply state:

```
dic[key] = value
```

> How can I increment the value of a certain key?

If you know for sure that the key is already part of the dictionary:

```
dic[key] +=  1
```

otherwise you can use:

```
dic[key] = dic.get(key,0)+1
```

> Or is there any other more easier way to do this?

You can use a `Counter` which is basically a dictionary with some added functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Using `pandas` and `scipy`

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine

line_dict = {'Karl': 1, 'Donald': 1, 'Ifwerson': 1, 'Trump': 0}
query_dict = {'Karl': 0, 'Donald': 1, 'Ifwerson': 0, 'Trump': 1}

line_s = pd.Series(line_dict)
query_s = pd.Series(query_dict)

print(1 - cosine(line_s, query_s))
```

This code will output `0.40824829046386291`

I didn't understand what you meant by "order" so I haven't dealt with that, but this code should be a good start for you.